# Serving Flask + Apache + WSGI Behind Sonicwall

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, sonicwall, flask

Strange problem here.  I've gone through [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) on setting up a deployment environment for a Flask app.

When I navigate to the servers local IP address it is serving everything fine. However there is a problem serving the Flask/Python logic externally I think.

Port 80 is open and successfully forwarding as shown with its current page (Index Of/Apache etc), but it is not showing "Hello, I love DigitalOcean" as it does within the local subnet.  It also was showing the default Apache HTML template before I enabled my Flask app in Sites-Enabled.

In my .conf file for Apache I currently have ServerName set to the local IP address.  My understanding was that all traffic to/from port 80 will be getting routed to that address anyways, and **it worked when it was just serving the static Apache HTML file externally.**

I'm super confused here, it's almost as if the python / flask logic is transferred on a different port and it isn't getting out!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had to change the ServerName in the .conf file to the actual hostname of the machine, as it matches my address object in my Sonicwall configuration. (I think that is the reason, however to be honest I'm not entierly sure.)